# Inorganic reactions related to nascent hydrogen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrogen

> Nascent hydrogen is prepared by
>
> (**A**) $\ce{Na}$ and $\ce{C2H5OH}$
> (**B**) $\ce{Al}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$
> (**C**) $\ce{Zn}$ and dil. $\ce{H2SO4}$
> (**D**) All of these

#### My attempt

I know that option (**A**) & option (**C**) are correct option. But don't know about option (**C**) and in the answer all of them are correct.

Can someone provide the complete reaction about option (**B**) and its important information such as similar reactions or mechanism?

Comment: Why downvote? I don't understand?!

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Questions are the central focus of this site, but we ask that questions demonstrate an attempt to solve/understand the question to maintain quality.  Please take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Zinc and sulfuric acid react to form nascent hydrogen. From [chem-guide.blogspot.com](http://chem-guide.blogspot.com/2010/04/atomic-hydrogen-nascent-hydrogen.html) (emphasis mine):

> […] if ordinary hydrogen is passed through acidified $\ce{KMnO4}$ it does not get decolourised. However, **if zinc pieces are added to the same solution, bubbles of hydrogen rise up** through the solution and the colour is discharged due to the reduction of $\ce{KMnO4}$ **by nascent hydrogen.**
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{KMnO4 + \underset{molecular}{H2} + H2SO4 &-> \text{No reaction}} \\
> \ce{Zn + H2SO4 &-> ZnSO4 + \underset{nascent hydrogen}{2H}} |\times 5 \\
> \ce{2 kMnO4 + H2SO4 + 10 [H] &-> K2SO4 + 2 MnSO4 + 8 H2O} \\
> \hline
> \ce{5 Zn + 8 H2SO4 + 2 KMnO4 &-> 5 ZnSO4(aq) + K2SO4 + 2 MnSO4 + 8 H2O} 
> \end{align}
> $$

See this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOItBmXz3dE) for more information.

As for the reaction given in option (B), see previous SE questions: [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/testing-a-sodium-aluminate-solution/9543#9543), [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49010/production-of-hydrogen-through-the-reaction-of-aluminium-metal-and-sodium-hydrox/49011#49011) and [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18872/is-atom-clean-aluminum-active-enough-to-react-with-alkali-salts/18883#18883).